# "Калькулятор" не извлекает корни

Tags: c++

Написал следующий код на C++

```
    #include <iostream>

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int a;
    int b;
    float res;
    char act;

    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> act;
    std::cin >> b;

    if (act == '+') {
        res = a + b;
    }
    else if (act == '-') {
        res = a - b;
    }
    else if (act == '*') {
        res = a * b;
    }
    else if (act == '/') {
        res = a / b;
    }
    else if (act == 'sqrt') {
        res = sqrt(a);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        res = 1;
    }
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Когда пытаюсь извлечь корень, выдает "Error" (тот который из моего кода). Что делать?  Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Если есть еще какая-нибудь критика по поводу кода, пишите, будет интересно.

Comment: `act` вообще-то один символ... А `'sqrt'` — это целочисленное значение 1936814708...

Comment: А как тогда быть?

Comment: Думать... Или сравнивать строки. А, кстати, у вас читает число - действие - число. Так что вам в любом случае надо вводить что-то вроде `2 sqrt 5` — и что это должно быть?

Comment: Последнее я еще не решил. А так спасибо)